# Is this circuit and values of component correct?

Tags: dc-dc-converter

[image]

[image]

I have traced out the PCB of a DC-DC converter (given.)

Is it correct (both circuit and values?)

**I need constant 5V output.  What modifications must I make?**

**updated**

In the datasheet of the LM2596  the diode used is schottky diode 1N582, but the DC-DC converter PCB uses a SS34.  Is that OK?

Comment: Looks pretty accurate to me but really kind of hard to tell since we can only see the top layer of this board.

Comment: not a very through "reverse engineering" job.

Comment: 471 = 470 uH, 470= 47uH !, , , RVT caps means 125'C rated low ESR

Answer (score 1):

Often modules like this are straightforward implementations of recommended circuits from the IC datasheets. And this one is pretty close to being exactly that. If you read the datasheet it will tell you everything you need to know to modify the circuit for a fixed output voltage.

R3 should be higher if you're really going to take the output voltage up to 35 V. 1 kohm is reasonable for fixed 5 V output.

R2 should probably be much lower. You can go work out what divider ratios you need between R1 and R2 to get the range of output voltages specified, based on the regulator's datasheet, and choose R2 to let you produce those ratios.

C1 and C2 are probably more like 10 uF than 100 uF.

L1 is more realistically 47 uH than 470. The [LM2596 datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2596.pdf) recommends values between 15 and 150 uH, depending on load current and input voltage.

The photo shows LM2596S-ADJ, but your schematic calls out LM2596S-5. If you want fixed 5 V output, then using LM2596S-5 is a good idea. You'd then get rid of R1 and R2 and just connect the FB pin directly to the output node.

Comment: The LED just seems like a bad design choice in general. It's basically impossible to select a value of R3 that'll result in the LED lighting at low voltages (particularly down below 5V) while not burning out when up at 35V. If it isn't needed, I would just remove it.

Comment: I need constant 5V output.

Comment: @Ravi, then you can get LM2596S-5 and just connect the FB pin directly to the output line rather than worry about feedback divider ratios.

Comment: @ThePhoton In datasheet of LM2596 the diode use is SchottkyRectifier,1N5825 but in DC-DC converter PCB use a SS34.Is it ok??

Answer (score 0):

R2 should be 330 ohms. L1 is 47uH, not 470uH. C1 and C2 should be 100nF (ceramic).

There should be a junction dot as shown below:

[image]

Other than those 5 errors it looks okay, but I might have missed something.

Comment: @ Spehro Pefhany  I need constant 5V output.what modification that i want to do?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany, you're right I deleted my comment. You get the whole adjustment range with or without the junction, but adding the junction will make the adjustment more linear. (But anyway, the question has been edited so the point is moot)

Comment: Replace the pot with the correct value of resistor (1K) or do as @ThePhoton suggests and use the fixed-output version of the SMPS chip. Note that the "NS" chip used in that module is probably a mis-marked clone and may not meet all the specifications of a genuine National Semiconductor (now TI) chip.

Comment: @ThePhoton response deleted as well. It's a cheap and cheerful/nasty Chinese module. Linearity .. mm.. personally I don't like the idea of a 5V supply that can be adjusted up to almost the input voltage (so you're operating on the bottom 10% of the trimpot element) but what can one expect for less than 60 cents for the whole module?

Comment: Another major error is drawing the feedback line so close  to the magnetic flux of the inductor.  Generally we don't care about EMI in logic diagrams, but here is it can affect ripple from crosstalk.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 Fortunately it's a shielded inductor. /s

Comment: I didn't think you could tell https://www.we-online.com/catalog/en/WE-TDCHV/ now I know